# Get decoded attachment file size with gmail API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

I am using google's [php client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) to talk to the gmail api.

I am attempting to report the file size of an attachment using this API.

I to test this, I sent myself an email with an attachment. I knew the size of this attachment to be 511KB. The gmail web ui reports this attachment as 499KB, which I suppose is close enough:

[image: 499KB image]

When I fetch this image using the [gmail json api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments/get), however, I do get the correct attachment size:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14ef5015d08312fd/attachments/ANGjdJ-Yy2H2avT5aFV7akMM2Lp4NigSpHqKgMT48zUMPVe3l6B9U0cfs-jXYD3cWJPhEwVjXQxNg2ZGDBFXKpMnf1HbpoBCwzcuOYSAJmHBbMHGANWKynofHf5GyStvjHhvNpA5xwla2hj7zdm6SVISoMgAR-dHJIPXbRniHVdryv13bxNsUeuRFvYbktnAcIwi-ppD6C1VAJtnGQYIKtNjsOa68hOlMSGLByWOrbB2txEN_P4cM43U7SEEzFmIDjFhKGkEIiU1rvrf9WT8KFVTsJ1U9_nTFjfkXIjl_Q?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

returns

```
{
 "size": 510808,
 "data": "encoded_data_string_uiasd82187"
}
```

So there is a slight disconnect between what the gmail web UI shows and what the actual size of the attachment is. But here's where it gets weird:

When I make a request for the [whole message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) (not just the attachment) aka, a request like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14ef5015d08312fd?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I get a json response like this:

```
"body": {
     "attachmentId": "ANGjdJ9P-2Q_1lMch1_smv_ZKACDE_QRtBisZ8bAWP1x_-ze8tvQiQunNCjcWUDkv2kjZo67AETe6Zmti5YZ3Zl4-EyaNtbtfxWOHBhTqQFSK673hZhEWW8Bg7Ul4ws2eOSYXrZsvWY8NhLptXJP5PM0W30LZk2sHj4XLWlmU64YxMPAOXwLOT1FeNc3EgVvlKJFQv1sUVajmA6c1K_qKgH_Y_c56fSJAz9aFRoh9RW6wvkhTV5NeLm9WFghkzpInwz6cm-DyJQhY-eOZLE2mvqQ4EmCPmBgzwNDh29mqQ",
     "size": 699004
    }
```

So the attachment with the ID that I'm looking for seems to have a size of 699KB, NOT the 511KB true size. This seems to be the size of the encoded attachment rather than the raw file.

So, using the PHP client library, when I have a `Google_Service_Gmail_MessagePart` representing this attachment, and I call `$messagepart->getBody()->getSize()` this returns 699004.

What I need is the true size of the attachment, 510808.

How can I get this true size, and is there a bug in the gmail API showing the wrong size in this context?

Comment: I've filed a [bug](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4498) on the Google Apps APIs issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the downside of base64-encoding, I'm afraid.

> Very roughly, the final size of Base64-encoded binary data is equal to
>   1.37 times the original data size + 814 bytes (for headers). The size of the decoded data can be approximated with this formula:
>
> bytes = (string_length(encoded_string) - 814) / 1.37
>
> *Wikipedia*

This fits your example very well (511 * 1.37 ≈ 700).

Comment: I'm using this but ignoring the constant 814 -- for large files, this won't be significant and for very small files it will be misleading (a 500 byte file would appear to be ~-500, which seems super wrong).